# Changing Local Axes?

Tags: transform-orientation

It's likely I'm missing on some fundamental understanding here.

[image]

I'd like to change the planets' local axes to match the global.  So in Object mode, I rotate Z90.  So far so good.

I thought the next step would be to Apply the Rotation change.  However, Apply changes the rotation back to default.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

The problem was I had all the planets Parented to an empty at the sun's position.

Once I unparented the planets, I was able to Apply the change and have it stick.

Answer (score 0):

You could rotate it in edit mode - this shouldn't affect the object's local rotation so you should be able to get it to match the global?